# CONCAT or REPLACE based on existance of value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace, concatenation

I have a simple sql query like below

```
SELECT REPLACE('TEST ABC XYZ NO JJJG', 'DEF', 'YES')
```

This will return same string as old one. I want here 'TEST ABC XYZ NO JJJG YES' as out put. If text exists, it should replace the text, else it should be appended at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `column` contains 'TEST ABC XYZ NO JJJG', then you could write a query like this:

```
SELECT
    IF(
        REPLACE(column, 'DEF', 'YES') = column, -- If the replacement yielded no changes
        CONCAT(column, ' ', 'YES'), -- Simply append the text
        REPLACE(column, 'DEF', 'YES') -- Otherwise returned the replaced result
    ) AS replaced_column
```

EDIT: To your comment (Simply change [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) with [`INSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)):

```
SELECT
    IF(
        INSTR(column, 'DEF') = column, -- If the column contains the text
        REPLACE(column, 'DEF', 'YES'), -- Replace the result
        CONCAT(column, ' ', 'YES') -- Otherwise append the text
    ) AS replaced_column
```

Comment: This script will create an issue. There will be  condition, when tobe replaced text and replaced text may be same. I mean like below                                    SELECT
    IF(
        REPLACE(column, 'YES', 'YES') = column, -- If the replacement yielded no changes
        CONCAT(column, ' ', 'YES'), -- Simply append the text
        REPLACE(column, 'YES', 'YES') -- Otherwise returned the replaced result
    ) AS replaced_column,                                                                          This case string will be appended